# JOptionPane breaks scanner input if keyboard is pressed

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, java.util.scanner, joptionpane

I've simplified the issue to the code below.

When ran, you see a message.

If you use the mouse and click on 'ok', then you can continue to type new commands.

If you press 'enter' or 'space' on the keyboard, then keyboard input breaks. I.e one can type things into the command line but a 'return' doesn't do anything.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true){
            System.out.println("hello, please enter your command");
            String UsrCmd = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("you tyep: " + UsrCmd);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,"Dialog Text","Title Text",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

            //Work around for Linux users:
            //Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/zenity --info --text='hello'");
        }
    }
}
```

(I'm new to S.o.f. I apologize for mistakes in advance. Please kindly correct me where I make them. Thank you).

JR 1.7 Fedor 20 64bit.

Comment: Your code works fine for me when I test it.

Answer (score 0):

It should work normally, since you dont have any statement that could stop the while execution, or a break; command. However, I would advice you to use JDK(java developer kit) instead of JRE.

Comment: It should work, but doesn't according to OP. Ask him questions in comments, say if you have tried the code on your own system (which one?). If he compiles Java code, I guess he has a JDK.

Comment: Sorry but I can not comment in other posts yet since I dont have the required reputation. However, by this answer I meant that its not a code problem but rather a software one(maybe OS). I tested myself the code with JDK 1.7.0_45 and it is working fine. My OS is Windows 7 x64.

Comment: I have tried both JDK and JRE, unfortunatley both result in the same thing.